# Get a list of mapped drives as a Windows service.

Tags: c#, service, windows-services, wmi, mapped-drive

I'm trying to get a list of mapped drives on my machine as a Windows service. I can get a proper list if I run my code as a normal program, but not as a Windows service. I've seen several posts regarding this topic but none give a clear solution.

I'm running the service on the same account that created the service, and the service has admin rights.

Does anyone know how to properly do this?

Comment: Could you please clarify what this means I'm running the service on the same account that created the service, and the service has admin rights. Does this mean you are running the service as a regular windows users?

Comment: Yes. Since mapped drives are specific to a user, it will only show up for the user who created it. In other words, I'm using the account that will be able to see the mapped drive (I only have one connected).

Comment: To clarify the problem, are you saying that the account that the service is running as has mapped drives that aren't being reported?

Comment: @RufusL Yes, that is the problem. But, they aren't reported when I run my code as a service. They are reported if I simply run my code from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible

please see the following MSDN article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If a service is configured to run under a user account, the system always creates a new logon session for the user and starts the service in that new logon session. Therefore, a service cannot manage the drive mappings established within the user's other sessions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Windows 7 with UAC enabled, then the administrative session has different mapped drives then the regular user session. Open an administrative command prompt and run `net show` and check the mapped drive status.

Update: I have EnabledLinkedConnections set on my Windows 10 workstation so I don't see this issue there.

Comment: hmm...I'm on Windows 10

Comment: I have a special registry entry on my Windows 10 to not have the issue. I updated my answer.